# How to disable error messages to screen while mysql service is down

Tags: database

Our production environment got a problem and the mysql service was down. The all our drupal based sites show the error messages below which expose to many information.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in
>   lock_may_be_available() (line 164 of
>   /home/workspace/drupal7/includes/lock.inc).

I find this page ([via](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/watchdog)) about how to disable drupal errors, but have no effect when mysql is down.

Any one can give me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `<?php print $messages; ?>` in maintenance-page.tpl.php could fix this,  see http://drupal.org/node/332413#comment-2887676

Comment: Thx, it works well.

Comment: My fellow used another method, change default error reporting setting from **ERROR_REPORTING_DISPLAY_ALL** to **ERROR_REPORTING_HIDE** within the function **error_displayable()** in the file **/includes/errors.inc:163**. Which is better?

Comment: Neither is better.  The right way to do this is to set `$conf['error_level']` in settings.php, as in John C's answer.

Answer (score 8):

Having just run across the same issue, to avoid hacking the core files you can set the default error reporting level in your site's `settings.php` by adding the following line:

```
$conf['error_level'] = ERROR_REPORTING_HIDE;
```

Since the `error_level` variable is normally set from the database the setting otherwise defaults to DISPLAY_ALL if MySQL is down.

Note: this means the error level can no longer be configured through the admin interface (admin/config/development/logging).